# NullPointer exception while using Multithread in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, spring-annotations

I am new to multi threading. I was trying to save a List of Object in sql database using crud repository. but i am getting null pointer exception in the save operation.
Below is my code and exception.
Thread Class

```
public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{
  private MedicineService medServ = new MedicineService();
  private  Presciption pres ;

  public PrescriptionThread(Presciption pres) {
    this.pres = pres;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    medServ.savePrescription(pres);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class MedicineService {

@Autowired
private PrescriptionRepository presRepo;

public void storePrescription(List<Presciption> payload) {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (Presciption presciption : payload) {
        Runnable runnable = new PrescriptionThread(presciption);
        executorService.execute(runnable);
    }
    executorService.shutdown();

    while(!executorService.isTerminated()) {}
}


public synchronized void savePrescription(Presciption pres) {
        presRepo.save(pres);
}
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PrescriptionRepository extends CrudRepository<Presciption, Integer> {

}
```

I am getting exeption in 
    presRepo.save(pres);

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cerner.api.service.MedicineService.savePrescription(MedicineService.java:86)
at com.cerner.api.util.PrescriptionThread.run(PrescriptionThread.java:16)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

If i don't use thread and just say

```
for (Presciption presciption : payload) {
        presRepo.save(pres);
    }
```

It is working fine and i am able to save it to db. But i want to implement thread.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my thread class as below and i was able to get the bean.

```
public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{
private MedicineService medServ;// = new MedicineService();
private  Presciption pres ;

public PrescriptionThread(Presciption pres, MedicineService medicineService) {
this.pres = pres;
this.medServ = medicineService;
}

@Override
public void run() {
medServ.savePrescription(pres);
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as a result of here:

```
private MedicineService medServ = new MedicineService();
```

the instance 'medServ' was spring  IOC management,  if you 'new' it , maybe don't get a instance of 'PrescriptionRepository'  because it was '@Autowire' , it will be throw NPE when you call  `presRepo.save(pres)`. but if you don't use Thread means that not a instance is new by youself, so it can be  work fine

Comment: If i not understood wrong. You mean to say if i want to use Thread then i have to make the Object of MedicineService using @Autowired?

Comment: But if i do so, Will get null pointer exception inside the run method . for medServ.savePrescription(pres); as using Autowired we are not able to get the object there. Please suggest

Comment: public class PrescriptionThread implements Runnable{
  private MedicineService medServ ;
  private  Presciption pres ;

  public PrescriptionThread(Presciption pres,MedicineService medicineService ) {
    this.pres = pres;
    this.medServ  = medicineService ;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    medServ.savePrescription(pres);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

Comment: thank you. I changes my thread constructor and passed even the object of service. and Its working fine.